# Multiply blend mode between two RasterLayer in MapBox React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mapbox-gl-js

How can I apply a multiply effect between two RasterLayers in MapBox in React Native? I'm already doing this on a Leaflet map with CSS mix-blend-modes and it is very easy to implement and doesn't impact performance.

[It is unfortunately not direclty possible in MapBox](https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-gl-js/issues/48)

But I'm thinking that there could be a way to pre-compose the images together before sending the resulting image to the map.

Any ideas?

```js
<MapView
  rotateEnabled={false}
  pitchEnabled={false}
  style={styles.map}
  logoEnabled={false}
  scaleBarEnabled={false}
>
  <Camera
    zoomLevel={11}
    centerCoordinate={[6.308, 45.005]
    }
  />
  <RasterSource
    id='source1'
    tileUrlTemplates={['https://source1.com/{z}/{x}/{y}']}
  />
  <RasterLayer id='source2' sourceID='source2'/>
  <RasterSource
    id='source2'
    tileUrlTemplates={['https://source2.com/{z}/{x}/{y}']}
  />
  <RasterLayer id='source2' sourceID='source2'/>
</MapView>
```